# stuck at Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk... after adding firebase_admob plugin

Tags: flutter

i wanted to insert ads in my flutter app with the firebase_admob plugin. I've created and registered firebas & addmob id..But when i add the plugin in the pubspec.yaml file the Flutter run stuck at  Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
if i comment the plugin it's back to the normal.
I still have the problem with a new emulator

thanks for your help

here is the flutter doctor log :
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.6 at /home/krycil/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 18cd7a3601 (3 months ago), 2019-12-11 06:35:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/krycil/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /home/krycil/dev/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /home/krycil/dev/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[!] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5556 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Do you get a `Multidex Error` or something like that?

Comment: no... no particular error messages in the run console

Comment: did you change the android manifest? I suspect that there is something with initializing your android. also try to enable multidex in your android build.gradle based on [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) link.